# Search for more than one templates using the wikipedia api

Tags: api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am searching wikipedia using the Wikipedia API for all articles that contain the `Template:Death date and age` template. This can be done with the following request

http://en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&format=xml&eititle=Template%3ADeath%20date%20and%20age&eilimit=10

I would like to modify my query in order to search using two or more templates. For example I would like to retrieve articles that have `BOTH` "`Template:Death date and age`" and "`Template:Birth date`". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eititle` parameter accepts only single value, and AFAIK there is no other way to do this. This means that you'll have to make one request per template and then merge them in your code.

Another option would be to get access to [the `templatelinks` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTemplatelinks_table). You can get that either by downloading the `templatelinks.sql` [dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) or by getting access to [Tool Labs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Labs/Tool_Labs), from which you can access the database directly.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) for queries like this, since the api doesn't really support the kind of query you're doing.

Comment: ... or Freebase. That's a relatively simple MQL query.

Comment: But DBpedia doesn't really track templates, no?

Comment: so, the answer is that I cannot use queries with multiple parameters, while searching templates with "embeddedin"?

Comment: @svik, generally, with a query like the one proposed, they're trying to find the information the templates present, not the use of the template.  But, I think DBpedia uses the templates to put together the infomation.